# How to load a taxonomy term with case-sensitive?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I used this

```php
    $this->termStorage->loadByProperties(['name' => 'test']);
```

I got two terms: `Test, test.`
I want to get only one: `test`

This is working without case-sensitive:

```php
    $this->termStorage->getQuery()->condition('name', 'test', '=')->execute();
```

```php
    \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data', 't')
      ->condition('t.name', 'test')
      ->fields('t', ['name'])
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

```php
    \Drupal::database()->query("SELECT name FROM taxonomy_term_field_data WHERE name='test'")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: See this D7 topic, besides EntityFieldQuery being replace by EntityQuery this should still be valid for D8:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77780/best-way-to-make-an-entityfieldquery-query-be-case-sensitive

Comment: Alternatively just use PHP to compare the string with the loaded terms' names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve result with sensitive case, you can use **binary** in where clause:
Like this sql query.

`SELECT name FROM taxonomy_term_field_data WHERE binary name='test'`

For Drupal you can use `\Drupal::database()->select` with where conditions take a look [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/update-queries) .

Try this:

```
 $result = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data', 't')
    ->where(
      'binary name = :term_name',
      ['term_name' => 'test']
    )
    ->fields('t', ['name'])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```