# How to make loadByProperties or entityQuery case sensitive for field value

Tags: 8, entities, database

Neither [loadByProperties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x) or entityQuery are case sensitive. How to make it case sensitive? I'm using MySQL as a database but would rather have a portable solution if possible.

**With LoadByProperty**

```
$nodes = $this->entityTypeManager()
              ->getStorage('node')
              ->loadByProperties(['field_myfield' => $value]);
```

**With entityQuery**

```
    $entity_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('field_myfield',$value)
        ->execute();
```

You can, of course, build your own query as explained [in this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/287815/1761). But my question is specifically about using loadByProperties or entityQuery API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [`this`](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2068655) long issue thread, they add **sensitive case** support to **entityQuery**.

So instead of `=` operation you can use `= BINARY` or instead of `LIKE` you can use `LIKE BINARY`.
Try this:

```
$entity_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('field_myfield',$value, '= BINARY')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! But no luck with loadByProperties? I don't understand why the API provide entityQuery AND loadByProperties to be honest. I like API when their is one obvious way to do things. I will strictly use entityQuery in the future.