# How to make a case sensitive entity query?

Tags: 8, entities, database

My custom entity type comes with a string field for which I would prefer case sensitive queries. When I use

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('my_entity_type')
 ->condition('my_token_field', 'SomeSortofTokenString')
 ->execute();
```

the result will include all entities no matter if the string in `my_token_field` is written the same way or for example with lowercases only. `my_token_field` is set a base field of type string - maybe this is the problem?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287808/how-to-load-a-taxonomy-term-with-case-sensitive

Comment: Thx @4k4 - this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the issue in a comment under my question describes this is the way to go:

```
 $given_token = 'AbTg4576Ft6h6';
 $result = \Drupal::database()->select('my_database_table', 't')
    ->where(
      'binary my_token_field = :given_token',
      ['given_token' => $given_token]
    )
    ->fields('t', ['id'])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you already said, I think you should set case_sensitive to true in the field settings, like [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21Core%21Entity%21EntityQueryTest.php/function/EntityQueryTest%3A%3AtestCaseSensitivity). This can also be set in the config.

When digging in the code, I found that the condition function at some point leads to [translateCondition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21Sql%21pgsql%21Condition.php/function/Condition%3A%3AtranslateCondition) which checks if a field is case sensitive and automatically applies the binary option to the sql query.

Comment: This does not help as the question is about a base field in a custom entity, not a Field API field